# Neo4j Error | List<MyObject> | error- org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.InvalidPropertyFieldException

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a neo4j database, and one of the nodes in the database has the following:

```
public class Location
{

 . 
 .
 .
 @Property(name = "zone_quantities")
 private List<ZoneQuantity> zoneQuantityList;
}
```

When I try to use ogm to map the node into the object, I get the following error:

*Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.InvalidPropertyFieldException: 'com.livspace.atp.domain.InvSku#zoneQuantityList' is not persistable as property but has not been marked as transient.*

Neo4j version - 3.1.6

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ZoneQuantity {

    private String zone;
    private Integer quantity;

}
```

Comment: List<Integer> list -> this is working fine, but when I am using my own object it's giving exception.

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j-OGM does not know what to do with the custom type property `ZoneQuantity`.
It is either a relationship and has to get described as such e.g.

```
@Relationship("HAS_ZONE")
private List<ZoneQuantity> zoneQuantityList;
```

or you need to provide an `AttributeConverter` for your custom type (collection) that converts it into a database compatible type. For example something like this converter https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/typeconversion/NumberCollectionStringConverter.java#L37